# Vue prevent downloading images again when filter the products

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter, nuxt.js

I have a problem with filtering products.
There are products that I'm filtering with 
[Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties). Like in the following code.

```
computed: {
    selectedProducts() {
      return this.categories.find((el) => el.id === this.selectedCategoryId)
        .products
    },
  },
```

When I change the  `selectedCategoryId` it's working as expected. But in every changes images getting redownload. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you...

Comment: Which images are getting downloaded? please update you question it not completely clear.

Comment: There is no idea about the image what you are talking about and there is no hint on what are the other component could you at least provide entire component.